# Что такое декомпозиция в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, терминология

> Что такое декомпозиция в JavaScript?

Это одно и тоже с деструктуризацией?Или нет?

В  [этой](https://metanit.com/web/javascript/4.11.php) ссылке все написано но я не уверен все правильно ли там.Хотел бы уточнить конкретно.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring

Comment: @AlexanderChernin я написал что хотел уточнить конкретно эти ссылки и сам могу открыть и смотреть.

Comment: скорее проблема перевода либо транслитерации термина. Тут решили перевести его в таком виде. В скобках указано английский термин - и он явно о деструктуризации.

Comment: @Grundy спасибо я тоже так думал.Хотел просто уточнить.Если есть ответ можешь написать :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае был выбран не совсем удачный вариант перевода термина `destructuring`.

Неудачный из-за того, что термин *декомпозиция* уже имеет устоявшееся определение в общей теории:

> Декомпозиция — разделение целого на части. Также декомпозиция — это научный метод, использующий структуру задачи и позволяющий заменить решение одной большой задачи решением серии меньших задач, пусть и взаимосвязанных, но более простых.

И применяется скорее к архитектуре, чем к конкретной особенности одного языка.

---

В текущей статье, да - *декомпозиция* (объекта) является синонимом *деструктуризации* (объекта).

Answer (score 0):

Неканоническое определение, скопитырено с https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment

> Деструктурирующее присваивание – это специальный синтаксис, который
> позволяет нам «распаковать» массивы или объекты в кучу переменных, так
> как иногда они более удобны. Деструктуризация также прекрасно работает
> со сложными функциями, которые имеют много параметров, значений по
> умолчанию и так далее.

Пример оттуда же. Деструктуризации массива:

```
// у нас есть массив с именем и фамилией
let arr = ["Ilya", "Kantor"]

// деструктурирующее присваивание
// записывает firstName=arr[0], surname=arr[1]
let [firstName, surname] = arr;

alert(firstName); // Ilya
alert(surname);  // Kantor
```

Лично мне нравится вот такое его использование - возврат множества переменных из функции

```
function f() {
    let v1 = "dsfsdf";
    let v2 = 5;
    return {v1, v2};
}

// При одинаковых именах полей объекта и переменных
let {v1, v2} = f();

// при разных
let {v1:valueA, v2:valueB} = f();
```